# Use wifi in push notification on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, wifi, push-notification

I want to use BIS push notification .
Can I  use  wifi on the device blackberry without getting an account BIS?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. BIS push notification requires a BIS data service account. I would think that would be obvious. If Wi-Fi is avaialble and supports a connection to RIM servers the device will use Wi-Fi instead of carrier wireless, but you still need the account.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me What is the necessity of having this account. I will not even use it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Richards answer, Without a BIS account, RIM wont know how to deliver a push notification to you. This applies to not just push, but BBM , Pin messages etc.

You get this account if you have a blackberry data plan. This data plan is offered by carrier and they can access the RIM servers. Push messages to you will come from the RIM server to your carrier and then to you. Without the Blackberry data plan, RIM will not know how it can send you messages.